# Running ASP.NET MVC in a subdomain makes Html.ActionLink render broken links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am running MVC in a subdomain
http://test.domain.com  which points to the /Test directory on my webhost4life account.

```
Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
```

it renders a link to

http://test.domain.com/Test/Home/About  --  which gives a 404

the link should be ..

http://test.domain.com/Home/About

is there a way to override ActionLink to omit the /Test on render?

Thank you

---

**Experiment 1**

I added a route to the table like this...

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Test",  // Route name
     "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",  // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

and now action link renders links like this..
http://test.domain.com/Test/Test/Home/About/
when this is clicked it does **not** give a 404 but gives the *Home* controler *About* action.

**Result**

No more broken links but the site renders ugly urls.

Comment: It should be working the way you want already. But obviously it's not... I'm suspicious there there is something missing in your description.

Comment: What is the application's root folder? It seems like it's sitting in the root and not in your sub-folder.

Comment: the files are copied to the /Test directory.

in the webhost4life iis admin console,
the /Test folder has been made an Application Directory and 
the /Test folder is also set as a virtual directory (this happens automatically when it gets set as an application directory). 
 

in the subdomain pointing manager, 
subdomian  test.domain.com  points to /Test

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a site using lots of subdomains I use a nifty MVC extension from ITCloud called UrlRouteAttribute. It allows you to assign a route to every action as an attribute setting the path and name. I have extended this to allow fully qualified paths - so to include the domain/subdomain the controller should attach to. If this is something you'd be interested in I'll upload a copy somewhere.

Comment: It looks very simple for making routes. I looked at it here http://itcloud.codeplex.com/ and it looks good, if you have a sample you could post I'd love to see it.